# Preventing jQuery function to repeat effect twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a something like this :
When a user **mouseenter** DIV1 , the DIV2 will **fadeIn** and when the user **mouseout** DIV1 , DIV2 will **fadeOut**

But something weird is happening , when you hover in and out DIV1 quickly , the FADEIN and OUT effect of DIV2 will repeat the total number of your hovers in.

For example:
i quickly hovers in and out for 10 times @ DIV1 , DIV2 will continue to FADE IN and OUT for 10 times although my mouse is not hovering it.

I hope people understand what i'm saying.

CODE:

```
$('div1').bind('mouseenter', function() {
   $('div2').fadeIn(600);
});
$('div1').bind('mouseout', function() {
   $('div2').fadeOut(600);
});
```

Thanks and have a nice day .

Comment: Are you sure `div1` is the selector you're using?

Comment: Yes i had checked it many times

Comment: If the `ID`s are `div1` etc. you ought to use `#div1`, but as you say it's working that's not the problem I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the `mouseout` event that will stop all the existing animations

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XkmFy/

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the existing animation when you start a new animation instead of stacking them up:

```
$('div1').bind('mouseenter', function() {
   $('div2').stop().fadeIn(600);
});
$('div1').bind('mouseout', function() {
   $('div2').stop().fadeOut(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which stops the current animation so that the animation queue does not get filled up with deferred animations: http://jsfiddle.net/pQQ2G/.

```
$('#div1').bind('mouseenter', function() {
   $('#div2').stop().fadeIn(600);
});
$('#div1').bind('mouseout', function() {
   $('#div2').stop().fadeOut(600);
});
```

Also, you shuold use `#div1`. `div1` selects `div1` elements, whereas you have `div` elements I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('div1').bind('mouseenter', function() {
   $('div2').fadeIn(600).stop(true, true);
});
$('div1').bind('mouseout', function() {
   $('div2').fadeOut(600).stop(true, true);
});
```

hope it helps